# Open Source GUI testing tools for tesing WPF (C# using VS2010)

Tags: c#, testing

I new to testing.....I am looking for a Open Source GUI testing tools for tesing WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough I have used [White](http://teststack.github.com/White/) with some success in WPF projects, testing GUIs is always a big pain and in will always involve manual tests. I base my UI logic on the [MVVM architecture pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and then try to do all test related to GUIs in the ViewModel (so I can use a normal unittesting framework, like [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)) and keep the View as dumb as possible, without any XAML trickery or handcrafted custom controls. In a lot of projects I was able to get away with almost no automated GUI tests at all.